# viewController gets removed from [tabBarController viewControllers] array, when used for UINavigationController

Tags: uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

i have a TabBar with 5 ViewControllers. i am using that array of tabBarController to populating a SideBarMenu like in Facebook app.

When i use a viewController to set as RootViewController of UINavigationController, then this viewController gets removed from the array [self.tabBarController viewControllers].

Why is this happening and how can i prevent this?

```
return [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:
[[self.tabBarController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0]];
```

the viewController at objectIndex 0 gets removed and the [self.tabbarcontroller viewControllers] is returning only 4 viewControllers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A UIViewController can only have one parent. When you add the view controller from the tab bar to the navigation controller, the navigation controller detached the view controller from its previous parent and attaches it to itself. For more information about why this happens, read the Implementing a Container View Controller section of the [UIViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) documentation.

Comment: ah ok, thats interesting. can you recommend me a way how to use all my viewControllers globally as array? i am converting my app from tabbar application to sidemenu application

Comment: You could use other view controllers to proxy the user's navigation to the global view controllers. For example, consider that pressing an item in the sidemenu could instruct the tab bar to switch to the appropriate view controller. And when the tab bar switches, it highlights the current item. Of course, you could do it the other way to--have the side menu be the actual container for the views and the tab bar buttons would tell the side menu what to do.